# Setting ulimit correctly for PHP on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, security, ulimit

I have `/etc/security/limits.conf` set to the following:

```
nobody soft nofile 409600
nobody hard nofile 1024000
phpuser soft nofile 409600
phpuser hard nofile 1024000
httpd soft nofile 409600
httpd hard nofile 1024000
* soft nofile 409600
* hard nofile 1024000
```

However, php pages still display:

```
[...] failed to open stream: Too many open files [...]
```

Setting `ulimit -n 10000` looks to only be a temporary fix.

I also have the following set:

```
fs.file-max = 20970800
net.core.somaxconn = 1024000
kern.maxfilesperproc = 16638400
kern.maxfiles = 819200
```

Answer (score 3):

I see two potential problems.

### Your limit may not apply to phpuser

`phpuser` may ignore your new limit because it might not use PAM to "log-in", so `/etc/security/limits.conf` would not apply. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/356962/where-are-the-default-ulimit-values-set-linux-centos#485277) for more details.

### The system wide limit is reached

Your are changing users processes limits. **The kernel also has a system wide limit on the number of open file-handles.**

This might be your problem. You can check the value like this:

```
$ sysctl fs.file-max
$ sysctl fs.file-nr
```

[By default](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/file_table.c?id=v3.12#n481), **file-max shoud be 10% of your available system memory in kB**, which may not be a very big number: 4 GB RAM ~ 400000 files which is below the limit you are trying to set.

The [documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt?id=v3.12#n91) says:

> The three values in file-nr denote the number of allocated file
>   handles, the number of allocated but unused file handles, and the
>   maximum number of file handles. Linux 2.6 always reports 0 as the
>   number of free file handles -- this is not an error, it just means
>   that the number of allocated file handles exactly matches the number
>   of used file handles.

Comment: Is this normal? error: permission denied on key 'fs.file-nr' when you edit sysctl.conf

Comment: You should rather edit `fs.file-max`. You can try something like `sysctl fs.file-max=500000`.

Comment: @FrankThornton Also, I edited my answer for another possible problem (PAM).

Answer (score 0):

You can set ulimit permanently by editing limits.conf.check this link

http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/ulimit-how-to-permanently-set-kernel-limits-in-linux/

In case of php files see this thread too

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937515/failed-to-open-stream-too-many-open-files